# Failed to apply plugin [id 'realm-android']

Tags: gradle, realm

I just updated my realm gradle dependency to 2.0.1 and now android studio won't gradle-compile anymore, giving me the following error:

```
Error:(2, 0) No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultDependencySet.removeIf() is applicable for argument types: (io.realm.gradle.RealmPluginExtension$_setSyncEnabled_closure1) values: [io.realm.gradle.RealmPluginExtension$_setSyncEnabled_closure1@401bbb3e]
Possible solutions: remove(java.lang.Object), removeAll(java.util.Collection), removeAll([Ljava.lang.Object;), removeAll(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

When I try to clean the project, gradle tells me the following:

```
Error:(2, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':commons'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'realm-android']
   > Could not create an instance of type io.realm.gradle.RealmPluginExtension_Decorated.
```

I read somewhere, that this might occure if gradle can't find the specified plug-in in any of its repositories. I only have jcenter() specified in my repositories section. I tried updating from 2.0.0 to 2.0.1 because the following bug:

> didn't find class "io.realm.internal.network.NetworkStateReceiver"

edit: Apparently 2.0.2 works fine. I just found out in some comment in some bug that there's a version 2.0.2. This is a bit frustrating. :(

Comment: Yes, you should definitely upgrade to 2.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in 2.0.2, `removeIf()` exists only in Java 8; once that was replaced with something Java 7- compatible, the builds work again.